# Can foobar2000 be automated using Python's pywinauto?

Tags: python

I need to select an output device in the foobar2000 application. The flow should be:

```
open foobar2000->File->Preferences->Playback->Output
```

and I need to select a device in the list of available devices in Python such that I can configure the output device.

[image: See the image]